Changing the keyboard shortcut for the all-in-one Code Search and Feature Search in Visual Studio 2022
How do I assign different hotkeys for Code Search, Feature Search, and the filtered searches in the All-in-one search window?
For example, how would I remap the Ctrl+T shortcut to just file search?
In the Keyboard window, it's unclear what are the right command names for Code Search, Feature Search, etc.


Go to the Keyboard settings (Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard).
Choose the corresponding command that you'd like to change the keyboard shortcut for.




Search
Command




Code Search
Edit.GoToAll


Feature Search
Window.QuickLaunch


File search
Edit.GoToFile


Type search
Edit.GoToType


Member search
Edit.GoToMember


Text search
Edit.GoToText




Go to Press shortcut key and press the hotkey you'd like to assign to the command. Click the Assign button.

Keyboard window
